# VBA to copy cells from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a complete beginner with VBA code, so apologies in advance. I'm looking to copy certain columns from one workbook, where the data is all located on sheet one, to another workbook where the data is split over several sheets.

Every time I try this, I either get a runtime error or a compound error.  It did work once, however then threw up another error and hasn't worked since.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: seeing Your code would be awesome

Comment: Post your code if you want it fixed! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Otherworkbook As Workbook
Otherworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open("D:\abc.xls")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("aaa").Range("A1").Copy Otherworkbook.Sheets("bbb").Cells(1, 1)
```

copy from ThisWorkbook sheet aaa A1 to D:\abc.xls sheet bbb A1